# Where to set up windows shared folder on Windows 2008 Foundation Server?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Forgive me, I have very little knowledge of servers, this is going to be a learning experience :-)!

I just got a Dell T110 Server with 2008 Windows Foundation, this is the first time I've set up a server. I'm trying to set up a directory that all the client computers will have access to on our local LAN/WirelessLAN. I have the OS Partitioned off (on C) and another partition (D) which is where I will store my data. Do I just share that drive out like on windows 7? Or do I have to set up users and grand them access to the space?

This is a very basic installation, for a very small company. They have a mix of Windows 7, Vista, and XP, some are actually the home versions.

Comment: Those home versions are going to prove to be a headache. You should recommend they budget for either new OS licensing or new PCs altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you need to setup the File Services Role on the server and configure a share. This is similar to what you would do to "just share that drive out like on Windows 7", but there's some more features since we're talking about a server here.

[Microsoft's Technet documentation on this is here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770740%28WS.10%29.aspx)